# Unable to install PosgreSQL on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, postgresql

I have been trying to install PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu machine. I end up getting this error.

```
postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and installing it through the command.

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3`

But I'm getting the same error. Can someone help me out?

Comment: X-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/31039261/398670

Comment: apt is telling you something is wrong - check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I installed postgres-xc and uninstalled it. But it wasn't uninstalled properly. I finally uninstalled postgres-xc and psotgres-client completely by doing this.

sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status

After this I installed postgresql using

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

It worked :D

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would have been to run aptitute to remove postgres. Aptitude does the removal and makes sure that there are no broken packages.